# Is there any way you can get the date (timestamp) for the last facebook access time?

Tags: time, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I'm wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a field available from the Facebook Graph API. You could request it on their [Facebook Developer Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/), although it doesn't seem like a field they would add.